# In the recent DKIM vulnerability, how did someone determine key length by looking at headers?

Tags: cryptography, attacks

Having read this recent article : [Wired-DKIM vulnerability](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2012/10/dkim-vulnerability-widespread/?goback=.nmp_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1_%2a1), I have a couple of questions.

How can one determine the key length that is being used simply by looking at the headers ?

And I'm assuming the attack is as follows: correct me if I'm wrong:

1. Factor the private key (of short key length) by knowing the public key, the mechanism (i.e. RSA etc)
2. Spoof the e-mail, replace the DKIM hash with hashes illegally calculated
3. Fool the verifier into thinking that the e-mail's origin is proper

Comment: Interesting question. It's certainly an odd situation - I'll have to read into it.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. What is the question here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've written a DKIM parser and signer for Microsoft Exchange so this is pretty straightforward.  Just note that the public key stored in DNS isn't a typical public key, it is in a more compact form called "public key subject form".

> How can one determine the key length that is being used simply by looking at the headers ?

1. Do a TXT query for the following values in the header:
       `{s value}`._domainkey.`{d value}`   (omit brackets)
2. Extract the value named "p=" in the above DNS query
3. Use an ASN.1 parser to determine the key length and other things that are stored within the

Example Public 2048 bit key found in a DKIM "p=" query with an [exponent of 65537](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2335/396)

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoSd6ya7haEmQl1sWoEVVou8iC618evFqluT5zb
0aMEgBEfHSJRjT/FojPWqhjAtCYMAIggaE0ZxVzPDsMeRc3Mixy2WO9DWYAJuzwP7DyzUAclhGTfP4cG44SlbSsEsMM/91cu5zr9+TulnqPDxUyPvLZjGpJEHXoEWc4m
f6tbksyxZTI+wssw84NLfEs3VC4jN9P1CnfG2aTCC74lj1mePbEBCsg83+Ilz/dsDcH2FGmWVa5ytNCP7kkzyBYkfF09YpDiSXxowRGZbRkGveDvOP3ONUhLrXumpTP6
+/Hm34kbG/kGBSxNOXn8/2jf2m+08Bt8ci9Orzb2s8J81q6QIDAQAB
```

Simply paste this key into the [ASN.1 Javascript decoder](http://www.lapo.it/asn1js/) to figure out the key length.  Most programmers will just have a library to figure this out.

Comment: There are many software to facilitate brute force password hashes (john, cryptohaze, hashcat, etc). So, what software do you recommend for factoring an RSA key ?

Answer (score 3):

The RSA signature size is dependent on the key size. A 512 bit key produces a 64 byte long signature. The header ends with a Base64 encoded signature, so with padding my memory tells me that will be 88 bytes long. So, key length can be determined just by looking at a signature.

Factor the key, sign with the key (because you now have it), and send with all the expected headers.

For the longer version / explanation of this, see [RSA signature size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658728/rsa-signature-size) on StackOverflow.